# extracting dividend from ichart.yahoo.com in python

Tags: python, csv, url, extract

I am trying to extract data on dividend payments for stocks from ichart.yahoo.com. For example, I can do this for DIS from Jan 1, 2014 to Dec 31, 2015 by pasting this url to a browser:

http://ichart.yahoo.com/table.csv?s=DIS&c=2014&a=1&b=1&f=2015&d=12&e=31&g=v&ignore=.csv

This prompts me to open/save the data (as a csv or excel file) and it works fine. How can I extract the same data (two columns - dates and dividend payments) inside a python program and work on it as a list or pandas DataFrame?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You could just read the csv in pandas.

```
import pandas as pd
x= pd.read_csv("http://ichart.yahoo.com/table.csv?s=DIS&c=2014&a=1&b=1&f=2015&d=12&e=31&g=v&ignore=.csv")
print(x)
```

Output:

```
         Date  Dividends
0  2016-12-08       0.78
1  2016-07-07       0.71
2  2015-12-10       0.71
3  2015-07-01       0.66
4  2014-12-11       1.15
```

Comment: This certainly works! I am new to Python/online data extraction. Do you happen to know what does the last part of the url mean (ignore=.csv)?

Comment: It is a part of the URL you posted in your original post, I do not know the yahoo API, but what it means is defined by their API (and maybe listed in some documentation). If you just want to load a csv in pandas you can just use the same link you would use in your web browser mostly though.